# Is there a requirement that jms messages are sent at the end of a commit?

Tags: java, jms, jboss6.x, hornetq

I have the strange phenomenon that jms messages seem to be sent before the database commit actually happened.

Lets say I have a server operation foo() which sends a message to the client when its completed. The client then loads the changed data from the server. It now appears that the jms message is sent before the commit is actually done, so the client still gets the old data, because its request is still before the end of the original commit.

The whole server operation is definately transactional, because if an exception is thrown, the jms event is **not** sent.

is there any requirement in the jms specification that first all database commits have to happen, and then the jms message is to send, or is it up to the implementation in which order this happens?

We are talking about the default hornetq implementation in jboss 6.0.0.Final.

**Update:**

It seems I have the same problem as these guys: http://techstack.com/forum/websphere/34434-order-commits-xa-transaction.html

**Update 2:**

Another user with the same problem http://community.jboss.org/message/114459

Comment: I didn't understand certain parts of your question. Can you please provide more context on how foo() is invoked? It does matter if this is occuring in an MDB, as opposed to any other code where no transactional requirements have been set. By the way, database commits are tangential to the sending of JMS messages; the sending depends on the presence of a transaction manager.

Comment: the link makes it much clearer now. Can you check whether you are following the [programming paradigm specified in this document](http://www.odi.ch/prog/jms-tx.php)? Although it is for JBoss 4, most of the points are relevant, especially that of having the DB transaction isolation level of `READ_COMMITTED`, and that of using the `java:/JmsXA` to locate the connection factory.

Comment: @vineet-reynolds, Yes all transactional behaviour should be as it is supposed to be. I actually managed to shrink my problem to a very small example, I will see that I can update my question with it (it is still a bit unwieldy)

Comment: @Mauli Hi Mauli, I know its a very long time since this question was raise. But you managed to solve it?

Comment: @Mauli Hi Mauli, Were you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Gandhi not really, it will come down to the realization that this is a guarantee which can not be given. The transaction manager will know that the db transaction will be fine, so even if the message is sent at the very end, there is no guarantee that the dbms itself is finished (in the sense that the change is visible for a new transaction from the outside!) with the transaction (when the message arrives). The only mitigation we came up with, is to register to the afterCommit event, and send the message there. It's not perfect, but works fine in nearly all cases.

Comment: @Mauli Thanks for the response Mauli

Comment: @Mauli Hi Mauli, When you mean registering to afterCommit event, you mean using CDI events? Can you please have a check on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343688/cdi-event-observer-handling-on-server-crash-and-restart

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure your Connection Factory is part of the same XA transaction.

you have to set REQUIRES_NEW on the EJB as Gursel Koca said in another post here.

The simpler will be you using the JCA Connection Factory (usually at java://JmsXA)

Answer (score 0):

JMS operations are transactional, that is why jms message is delivered at commit time. If you want to see committed data, put db operations another EJB method with transactional property `REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: This is not what I want, the JMS Messages **have to be** in the same transaction. It just seems that the JMS messages are sent to early.