# CDI event observer handling on server crash and restart

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi, jboss7.x, java-ee-7

I am trying to persist an item in DB using a service and firing a JMS message for the subsequent service to pick up the persisted item so that it can process the same. This particular operations happens in a single transaction. But due to race condition at times, the second service is not able to fetch the respective item as its not yet persisted.

My use case is very common and there are so many discussions related to this in various forums. One solution for this issue is to use CDI events. I tried the same and could solve a part of the problem. The pseudo code is as follows:

```
@Inject
@Transaction
private Event<Item> itemEvent;

public void handleItem(Item item) {
  //code to persist the item
  itemEvent.fire(item);
}

@Asynchronous
public void observeAfterTransactionCompletion(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) @Transaction Item item) {
  //code to send JMS message to the second service
}
```

My only issue is when the persistence is successful & event is fired and just before the observer starts processing the event if the Jboss server goes down, the second service will not be notified as the JMS message wont be send.

Will the CDI container can internally handle this scenario so that the event will always be invoked? Will the observer be notified on server start automatically? If not, How do I handle this scenario so that my approach is fool proof?

**NOTE:** I have already tried out the retry approach in second service till the message is available. Also persisting the event in an other queue is an alternate approach which seems very tedious. Looking for a smart approach.

**UPDATE:** My initial code was written in such a way that the persistence and messaging was in single transaction. But that resulted in message consumption by second service before even first service persistence is successful resulting in error as second service could not find the required data which is yet to be persisted.

**UPDATE 2:** Intial approach pseudo code as follows:
`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void processMessage() {
   // code to persist data to DB
   // code to publish JMS message to the consumer
}`

Even by using xa-datasouce and xa-connection factory, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDI events are not persistent and hence they dont get re-triggered after server restart.

Finally we ended up resolving the issue by using DB persistence before publishing the message and splitting up persistence & publishing into two different transactions. However we need to handle message duplication ourselves in case of message publishing errors or server restarts before message publishing commits.

Comment: So effectively you implemented JMS?

Comment: @Kukeltje More or less we ended up implementing distributed transaction handling ourselves using an intermittent db table

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use XA transactions.

Both JMS and database resources join the same transaction, so the JMS message is fired on the commit, either an error in database update or in JMS message sending will trigger the rollback of the whole operation.

Note that you'll have to change the datasource definition do use `xa-datasource`, update the JMS connection factory configuration to use xa and that the JMS session must be transacted as well

```
 <!-- JMS connection factory configuration -->
 <pooled-connection-factory name="myCxFactory">
     <transaction mode="xa"/>
     [...]
 </pooled-connection-factory>

// JMS session creation (message producer)
Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
```

Note also that only the message production is part of the transaction, not his consumption

Comment: Thanks for the response Gab.In my case the persistence and messaging is in single transaction. But the message consumption happens before even data is persisted resulting in exception. I need to ensure that the message is sent only after persistence happens. That's were CDI events were handy except for the one scenario mentioned in my post

Comment: Please find my updated question and let me know your thoughts

Comment: Transactions are not shared between multiple resources unless you set up distributed one (XA). Using XA typically ensure what you need (the JMS message cannot be consumed before the database update is commited because it is not fired yet)

Comment: Hi Gab, Thanks again for the response. I already tried out changing my connection factory to pooled-connection-factory that uses XA transaction and also tried using xa-datasource. The issue still persists. The JMS message comsumption happens before even the persistent is complete. Have update my question by adding the code which does that. Please have a look.

Comment: if your database use xa-datasource, your JMS connection factory use xa transaction mode, your JMS session is transacted and both operation occur in the same transaction then it should work (my current software work like this).... I'am afraid I can't help you more

Comment: Will recheck on this and get back to you Gab. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Unfortunately no breakthrough yet. We are using 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' for persistence with transaction type - JTA. Any clue around this?

Comment: JTA is fine, the txManager must be provided by the server. I don't know eclipseLink, maybe you can try something like this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250874/spring-jpaeclipselink-with-jta-transaction-managerjboss-7-not-committing
You can also try to log (TRACE level) the jta tx manager output (com.arjuna.ats)

Comment: Thanks again Gab. Will have a check on this and keep you posted.

Comment: Sorry Gab. No luck yet after trying out all possible options.